# Transmission fluid shows to be over full and trans is slipping

Tags: ford, automatic-transmission, f-150

I have a 2005 Ford F150. The transmission starting having problems shifting today. When I checked the fluid, it shows to be way over full on the dipstick. I have not added any fluid since I have owned the truck, and when I bought it, all the fluids were at proper levels. What would cause the transmission fluid to now show over full and the trans to not want to shift properly?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! How exactly did you check your fluid?

Comment: On level ground with truck running. Truck had been running for over an hour and was operating at normal temp.

Comment: Good, good ... just making sure :o)

Comment: Is the coolant level a bit low?